# 21.10 Ghost application icons in top bar

Tags: gnome, icons, top-bar

Ubuntu 21.10
I keep getting these ghost application icons in the top bar[image: Ghost icons]

As you can see in the image they are only visible when hovering the mouse over them. There are so many that they have pushed my actual running app icons to the left. They appear over time and I have not been able to figure out what triggers their appearance (like a specific app I'm running). if I look at running processes I don't see 40 running apps. They are still there even if I close all applications.

Usually there are not this many but in this case you can see between the icon for Telegram and the wifi notification there are about 40 of these icons.
The only way to clear these that I have found is a reboot.
Right clicking on them does not bring up a menu.

I ran gnome-extensions and disabled Ubuntu AppIndicators. My running app icons dissapear as expected but these ghost ones do not.

I have seen other questions similar on here but they had identified the cause, that these appeared after waking up from being suspended. I do not suspend my laptop and have a tweak to not suspend if I close the lid. I checked anyway just by opening and closing the lid a few times and it does not cause these icons.
Any clues as to how I can figure out what is causing this?

Update: After a reboot they went away. So I've been watching closely to try to figure out what creates these ghost/null icons.
I just noticed one now. Didn't see it pop into existence but there it is.
Apps I have running:

- guake (has a top bar icon)
- Vivaldi web browser
- PyCharm Community Edition
- Signal (chat app)
- Telegram (chat app - has a top bar icon)
- Hotshots (screen capture app - has a top bar icon)
- gnome-extensions (the admin console)

Using the gnome-extensions app I figured out how to create more of these null icons.
If I disable  `Ubuntu Appindicators`, when I re-enable them a null icon appears.

However, this is not what I was doing for the ones to appear out of nowhere. Something else is creating those. I'll keep digging.

[image]

In response to @heynnema's comment:

```
marty@marty-aorus:~/Downloads$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
ls: cannot access '/home/marty/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory
```

and

```
marty@marty-aorus:~/Downloads$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 Dec 21 11:15 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:55 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:55 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Dec 21 11:15 dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:26 ding@rastersoft.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:55 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:55 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:55 native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:55 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:55 screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:26 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:55 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:55 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:55 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:55 windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:55 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

Comment: You probably have a bad gnome-shell extension. Disable ALL extensions except for the 3 system extensions, restart gnome-shell or logout/login, and see if the problem is gone. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema Edited answer with more information as you suggested

Comment: I see some likely suspects. Try this test... log into a different user account... temporarily create one if you don't already have one... and see if the problem occurs there. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I created a new user and logged in with that account. Opened and closed a bunch of apps. The problem did not occur but I might not have done whatever combination of events causes this issue.

Comment: Temporarily uninstall the "Dash to Panel" gnome-shell extension and let's see if my first guess is correct.

Comment: @heynnema I uninstalled 'Dash to Panel' as you suggested. After about 3 hours usage now the issue seems to have been fixed. Thanks!! Can you write this as an answer rather than a comment so I can mark it as solved?
I am curious as to why the extension was behaving like that, but glad it is fixed. I didn't use the extension anyway, I just installed to check it out. So no problem not having it installed.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

gnome-extensions can be fun, but they can also cause problems. The only way to diagnose for potential problems is to disable/remove one extension at a time, restart gnome-shell (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, `r`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>), and retest for the problem.

In this case, I reviewed the installed gnome-shell extensions, and I determined that this one was a good candidate for causing the user's problem.

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Dec 21 11:15 dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com
```

So we removed this extension, restarted gnome-shell (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, `r`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>), and the problem is gone!

**Note**: I'm not a fan of the **@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com** extensions either. I'd recommend that you remove any that you don't need/use. Use these commands to see these:

`ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

`ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`